# Understanding the solution to $4^{3x+6}+3^{2x+3}=4^{3x+4}+2\times3^{2x+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

For the last 5 hours I tried to solve the equation below (without luck).
$$4^{3x+6}+3^{2x+3}=4^{3x+4}+2\times3^{2x+4}$$

A friend of mine then told me that the solution is
$$\frac{\ln(16/3)}{\ln(3/8)}$$

Can anyone help me understanding why this is the solution? No matter how I turn it, I never get to this solution.

My last final solution was
$$\frac{\ln(135)-\ln(16)}{\ln(64)-\ln(9)}$$

I'm looking forward to your answers, as I'm quite desperate at the moment.

Comment: Where is the picture?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  There's no equation pictured here. Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$4^{3x+6}+3^{2x+3}=4^{3x+4}+2 \times 3^{2x+4}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 16(4^{3x+4})+3^{2x+3}=4^{3x+4}+6(3^{2x+3}) $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 15(4^{3x+4})=5(3^{2x+3}) $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 3(4^{3x+4})=3^{2x+3} $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \ln(3)+(3x+4)\ln(4)=(2x+3)\ln(3)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x(3\ln(4)-2\ln(3))=2\ln(3)-4\ln(4)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{2\ln(3)-8\ln(2)}{6\ln(2)-2\ln(3)} = - \frac{\ln\left( \frac{16}{3}\right)}{\ln\left( \frac{8}{3}\right)}$$

so your friend is right !